# add class in Jhtml joomla

Tags: class, joomla

this code for display virtuemart product image:

```
                              <div class="img-wrapper">
                                <?php
                                        $image = $product->images[0]->displayMediaThumb('class="browseProductImage featuredProductImageFirst" id="Img_to_Js_'.$product->virtuemart_product_id.'" border="0"',false) ;
                                        if(!empty($product->images[1])){
                                         $image2 = $product->images[1]->displayMediaThumb('class="browseProductImage featuredProductImageSecond"  border="0"',false) ;
                                        } else {$image2= $product->images[0]->displayMediaThumb('class="browseProductImage featuredProductImageSecond"  border="0"',false) ;}
                                        echo JHTML::_('link', JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=productdetails&virtuemart_product_id='.$product->virtuemart_product_id.'&virtuemart_category_id='.$product->virtuemart_category_id),'<div class="front">'.$image.'</div><div class="back">'.$image2.'</div>');
                                ?>
                              </div>
```

output above code in front site:

```
<div class="img-wrapper">
<a href="link to product">
     <div class="front">
         <img show_image1_product > 
     </div> 
     <div class="back">
         <img show_image2_product > 
     </div> 
</a>
```

now,I want add class to  `<a href="link to product">`
how do it?

Comment: what about using `.img-wrapper a {}` in your CSS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JHTML` link accepts associative array as third parameter (as written in [docs](https://docs.joomla.org/API17:JHtml::link)), so you can use `["class"=>"classname"]`

**EDIT**: full line of code to better understand, what is nicely explained in [documentation](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JHtml.html#method_link)

> JHTML::*('JoomlaClassName',
>   JRoute::*('UrlOfLink'),'TextWithFrontBackDivs',AssociativeArray);

```
JHTML::_('link', JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=productdetails&virtuemart_product_id='.$product->virtuemart_product_id.'&virtuemart_category_id='.$product->virtuemart_category_id),'<div class="front">'.$image.'</div><div class="back">'.$image2.'</div>', array("class"=>"classnane"));
```

Comment: how use it in code?                                          echo JHTML::_('link', JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=productdetails&virtuemart_product_id='.$product->virtuemart_product_id.'&virtuemart_category_id='.$product->virtuemart_category_id),'<div class="front">'.$image.'</div><div class="back">'.$image2.'</div>');

Comment: check the modified answer

Comment: thanks moped,but don`t worked..when use above your code, not show any image div...

Comment: then try it with `array("class"=>"classnane")` instead of `[]`